# How to associate two tables at Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm doubt. There are two tables called `type_agricultural_implement` and `agricultural_implement` where `type_agricultural_implement_id` it's inside of `agricultural_implement` as `type_agricultural_implement_id`. It's a relationship 1:N. But I don't know if it's correctly my code.

### Model - type_agricultural_implement

```js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const type_agricultural_implement = sequelize.define(
    'type_agricultural_implement',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(90),
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'type_agricultural_implement',
    }
  );
  type_agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    type_agricultural_implement.hasMany(models.agricultural_implement, {
      foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id',
    })
  }
};
```

### Model - agricultural_implement

```js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const agricultural_implement = sequelize.define('agricultural_implement', {
    agricultural_implement_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'agricultural_machine',
        key: 'agricultural_machine_id'
      }
    },
    type_agricultural_machine_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'type_agricultural_machine',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'agricultural_implement'
  });

  agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    agricultural_implement.belongsTo(models.type_agricultural_machine, { foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id' });
  };

  return agricultural_implement;
};
```

Is my code rigth?

[image]

Comment: Everything looks fine except this `type_agricultural_machine`. Shouldn't it be  `type_agricultural_implement`?

Comment: The name ```implement``` it's that could be anything linked with agricultural, like tractor and etc

Comment: I am talking about this `agricultural_implement.belongsTo(models.type_agricultural_machine, { foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id' });` Here you are making association with wrong model.

Comment: I resolved the problem, at the model ```agricultural_implement``` I put the wrong name with references, and associations. HAHAHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, at my Model `agricultural_implement` where there are

```js
type_agricultural_machine_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'type_agricultural_machine',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'agricultural_implement'
  });

  agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    agricultural_implement.belongsTo(models.type_agricultural_machine, { foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id' });
  };
```

I put wrong names at where there are `type_agricultural_machine_id` will be `type_agricultural_implement_id`, the `references` is the same and associations too.